# Run gulp build locally or after deployment?

Tags: gulp

What is the best practice, and what are the advantages and disadvantages of these alternatives:

1. run gulp build process locally. this includes a watch for change, and uglify js/css. when committing & deploying, the dist files are committed and deployed as is
2. make the gulp build on the server on deployment. this can be only for the staging/testing server, and not for the production server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our flow is that every developer runs gulp locally, with watching js/css/templates etc, dist files are in gitignore. You commit and push only source files. When deploying, you can have another gulp wrapper task, that does not have watch in it, you just pull the changes from the origin and run gulp deploy.

If you had your dist files in your repo, you would not avoid conflicts when fetching...

Btw, why this can be for the production server?

Comment: I thought maybe it's better not to have it for the production so it won't be another point of failure, plus so it will be exactly like the staging env. also, why do twice the same job?

Comment: I guess it's all about the dev env. The flow I provided is the best one we could come up with, when speaking about legacy sites, small ones, big ones. How do you plan to solve the conflicts you would have with other developers?

Comment: each time someone commits  to staging, he builds

Comment: What are you using for your deployment process? With TFS we just have a build step that runs a `gulp prod` task and we run `gulp watch` locally when developing. Don't (or try not to) commit generated files.